# Running 'code .' in terminal in wsl produces an error

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, wsl-2

I recently installed wsl and running `code .` in the terminal I get this error:

```
Updating VS Code Server to version f80445acd5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d97cc326
Removing previous installation...
Installing VS Code Server for x64 (f80445acd5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d97cc326)
Downloading: 100%
Failed
--2022-03-01 20:19:21--  https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:f80445acd5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d97cc326/server-linux-x64/stable
Resolving update.code.visualstudio.com (update.code.visualstudio.com)... 40.64.128.224
Connecting to update.code.visualstudio.com (update.code.visualstudio.com)|40.64.128.224|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://az764295.vo.msecnd.net/stable/f80445acd5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d97cc326/vscode-server-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2022-03-01 20:19:25--  https://az764295.vo.msecnd.net/stable/f80445acd5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d97cc326/vscode-server-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving az764295.vo.msecnd.net (az764295.vo.msecnd.net)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘az764295.vo.msecnd.net’
ERROR: Failed to download https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:f80445acd5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d97cc326/server-linux-x64/stable to /home/burbanox/.vscode-server/bin/f80445acd5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d97cc326-1646176740.tar.gz
```

I need to know how I can solve it to be able to open visual studio code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Don't worry, your question was perfectly clear even before the edit.  The fact that a reviewer didn't have the subject-matter-expertise to understand it is a problem with the review (they should have clicked *"Skip"* on the review), not a problem with your question.

Comment: This looks like a network failure of some sort in WSL.  What happens if you `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`?  Does that work?  How about if you try downloading that same file from PowerShell?  `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:f80445acd5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d97cc326/server-linux-x64/stable" -OutFile "f80445acd5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d97cc326-1646176740.tar.gz"` (from a directory where you can write, of course).

Comment: Hello thanks, after `sudo update and upgrade` and then  `code . ` the same error appears,  but in power shell looks like work fine.

Comment: Did you fix the issue? I am also having the same problem

Answer (score 9):

I managed to find a somewhat orthodox solution

1. First Open Vscode locally via windows
2. Go to View in upper section and select "command palette"
3. Select the option "Remote-WSL: New WSL Window "

Answer (score 6):

wget: unable to resolve host address ‘az764295.vo.msecnd.net’
try this :

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

edit name server to 8.8.8.8:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: what does this do?

Comment: @FrancescoPegoraro this config set 8.8.8.8 (https://dns.google/)  as your DNS.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open VS Code from Windows
2. Open command palette `Ctrl + Shift + p`
3. Type `WSL` and select option `WSL: connect to WSL using Distro`
4. Select your distro, for example `Ubuntu-22.04`

Now if you try command `code .` from WSL it should work.

This seems to me a network issue in WSL. By doing the above steps, the vscode gets updated from the windows side instead from inside WSL which was failing previously.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue.

Solution:

1. Go to the search bar and type "Turn windows features on or off",
   scroll down to Windows Subsystem for Linux, and uncheck it.
2. Restart
3. Go back to "Turn windows features on or off", which can also be located in the control panel, and recheck the box for Windows Subsystem for Linux
4. Restart

   Now you can open to command prompt and type:

   ```
   wsl -l -v #this will verify which version you are running. mine remained the same at wsl 2. if it is not you can change it.
   wsl --set-version Ubuntu20.04 2
   ```
5. Open your Ubuntu command line and try retyping (`code .`) and it should install the proper packages.

   ```
   taylor@DESKTOP-TI4J8NI:~/Desktop/OS_Python$ code .                                                                                                             
   Updating VS Code Server to version 3b889b090b5ad5793f524b5d1d39fda662b96a2a                                                                                    
   Removing previous installation...                                                                                                                              
   Installing VS Code Server for x64 (3b889b090b5ad5793f524b5d1d39fda662b96a2a)                                                                                   
   Downloading: 100%                                                                                                                                              
   Unpacking: 100%                                                                                                                                                
   Unpacked 2822 files and folders to /home/taylor/.vscode- 
   server/bin/3b889b090b5ad5793f524b5d1d39fda662b96a2a.
   ```

Following this, everything was working for me again. Recap: Just disable and re-enable the Windows Subsystem for Linux feature.

Answer (score 1):

After recovery found, I found a solution to this problem:

1. open ThisPC
2. open Linux
3. open Ubuntu => home => find folder vscodeServer => delete it
4. again install vscodeServer by code.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5256#issuecomment-666545999) to fix the networking issue and it works fine afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to proxy but always make sure you try to reboot the laptop, then run `sudo update` and `sudo upgrade`, check the proxy then open the terminal and type `CODE`.